# About GitFlow Development

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm using the GitFlow template.

I have two branch: `master` and `development`. 
Last week I discovered a minor bug in the system and created a branch called a `bugfix/bug-name`.

The bug has already been resolved but I have not yet released the software.

Today I will include a new feature in the system. Which way is right?

1. Start the new functionality from the bugfix;
2. Start the new functionality from the `development` and then when you finish merge the two to the `release/x.x.x.x` branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the gitflow branching scheme, you don't usually merge non-integration branches with each other. Everything is eventually merged into integration branches `development` (for unreleased stuff) and/or `master` (for releasing).

If the bugfix branch was branched off of `master`, it is a "hotfix" branch and should be merged to `master` and `development` (and then deleted).

If the bugfix branch was branched off of `development` it should be merged back to development (and then deleted).

If you've already started working on the new feature on its own branch (which probably has branched off of `development`) and if you need the bugfix on the feature branch, then merge `development` into the feature branch after the bugfix has been merged into `development`. If you don't need the bugfix while developing the feature, just wait until the feature is ready and is being merged into `development` where the bugfix will already have been merged.

If you haven't started working on the feature, simply create the feature branch from `development` after the bugfix has been merged there.

Comment: I have not started the new branch of `feature`. In this case, I merge the `bugfix` to `development` and then from the `development` started the new branch `feature`. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Either option will work if you know how to merge, making a new branch from `bugfix` or `development` are good options, but I would recommend it to do it from `bugfix` so it will be easier to merge with `development` later.